# Constraint Error warning using Enum in ADA

Tags: enums, ada, gnat

I'd like to know why constraint Errors warnings are prompted in Ada when enums are used as in the example below. As I've been using Enums  I can replace them for a better implementation.

```
type Uart_Instance_Type is (COM1, COM2, COM3);

for Uart_Instance_Type use
  ( COM1   =>    16#0001# ,
    COM2   =>    16#0002# ,
    COM3   =>    16#0003# 
  );

  type UART_Register_Type is record
    SR         : Half_Word; -- USART Status register
    Reserved_0 : Half_Word;
    DR         : Half_Word; -- USART Data register
    Reserved_1 : Half_Word;
    BRR        : Half_Word; -- USART Baud rate register
    Reserved_2 : Half_Word;
  end record
  with volatile;

  for UART_Register_Type use record
    SR           at  0  range 0 .. 15;
    Reserved_0   at  2  range 0 .. 15;
    DR           at  4  range 0 .. 15;
    Reserved_1   at  6  range 0 .. 15;
    BRR          at  8  range 0 .. 15;
    Reserved_2   at 10  range 0 .. 15;
  end record;

type UART_Register_Access is access all UART_Register_Type;

UARTs: array (Uart_Instance_Type range COM1 .. COM3) of aliased UART_Register_Access;
```

The compiler prompt at the last line ("UARTs: ...) and shows:

```
  warning: "Constraint Error" may call Last_Chance_Handler
```

Is there a better implementation to avoid these warnings when using Enums?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What compiler do you use? And what is the definition of `UART_Register_Access`?

Comment: I have added its definition in the code above.

Answer (score 4):

I think you must be compiling for a restricted (Ravenscar?) runtime, which is why *any* exception will result in a call to `Last_Chance_Handler`.

I encountered a *lot* of irritating warnings like this, and eventually traced it to compiling with
`-gnatwa` (“turn on all info/warnings marked below with +”) which enables
`-gnatw.x` ("turn on warnings for non-local exception”).

You can suppress the warnings with `-gnatw.X`.

(For info, you can see the command line options by saying `gnatmake -h` (or `arm-eabi-gnatmake -h`). There are a lot.)

Comment: in other words there's no problem with the actual code (which Gnat 4.9.2 compiles OK). I wonder if `UARTs: array (Uart_Instance_Type) of ...` would suppress the warning by allowing all the COM ports instead of an (admittedly complete) subset.

Comment: Yes, I am compiling for a restricted Ravenscar. I thought there might be something wrong with my implementation and that's why I got these warnings. For instance, if I use a case statement for variable of the type `Uart_Instance_Type`, it always prompt the same warning as above but if I use the "if / else" then it doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: I have to say it looks like a bug. Perhaps it’ll be fixed in GNAT GPL 2015. @BrianDrummond, compiling a package with `pragma Profile (Ravenscar)` using the hosted compiler doesn’t show any problem, `pragma Restrictions (No_Exception_Propagation)` shows the problem in the spec if and only if the enumeration representation is present, and shows the problem with case statements regardless of the enumeration representation.